# Is the cohomology of rigid varieties semisimple?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $X$ be a smooth projective geometrically connected scheme over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Assume that $H^1(X, T_{X/\mathbb{Q}_p})=0$.

Is the Galois representation $H^*(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}}, \mathbb{Q}_l)$ semisimple for sufficiently large $l$?

Comment: Conjecturally, Frobenius is semisimple, so this would be equivalent to the unipotent part of the inertia action being trivial. Regardless, it implies that the unipotent part of the inertia action is trivial. This action is generically nontrivial for a variety with bad reduction so I imagine you will find many examples.